# Transforming Lat/long data to UTM --2 different UTMS

Tags: latitude-longitude, utm

I am trying to transform Lat/Long data from Italy (UTM 32 and 33) to UTM. I am struggling a bit with this.

The code I am trying to use is one I found in a previous post, I tried to modify it to solve the problem of several UTMs but does not seem to work.

> df <- data.frame(x = Data_group_malesCLEAN$Latitude, y =
>   Data_group_malesCLEAN$Longitude, ID = Data_group_malesCLEAN$Group.1)
>
> long2UTM <- function(long) {   ## Function to get the UTM zone for a
>   given longitude   (floor((long + 180)/6) %% 60) + 1 }
>
> LongLatToUTM <- function(df){   coordinates(df) <- ~x+y
>   proj4string(df) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
>
> zone <- long2UTM(df$x)
>
> ## Change CRS of the spatial data frame and convert to data frame
>
> res1 <- spTransform(df, CRS(paste0("+proj=utm +zone=", zone,
>   "+datum=WGS84")))   return(as.data.frame(res1)) }
>
> res1

I also tried to do it with Qgis... but I am in the same problem... It is only possible for one UTM,... any ideas?
Best

Comment: I don't understand the code, but a data frame / map can only use one coordinate reference system. Are you taking that into account?

Comment: mkennedy, thanks. However Italy fells between 2 UTMS 12 and 13, and my dataset has data from all Italy, so I was wondering How I could approach this. Because even in Qsig for instance, you only can use one UTM... any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to decide to use one, or use another coordinate reference system that covers the entire area of use.